# How to show top loading bar on every route change in next js 13 app directory?

Tags: next.js, loading

I want to show top loading bar or spinner at the top of page when I try to change page in next js 13 (or 14). When I change page, there is no signal of changing the route? How can I do it. Also I used a package for it but it shows loading only when I used Link component and not when I use router.push() from next/navigation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', (url) => {
      console.log("handle showing a loading");
    });

    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', (url) => {
      console.log("handle hiding loading");
    });

    router.events.on('routeChangeError', (url) => {
      console.log("handle hiding loading");
    });

  }, []);
```

Comment: some auto way? I mean with the use of some framework?

Comment: there are some different events according to nextjs documentation from this link https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#routerevents , by using them you can do what ever you want  like setting some (useState) to show a loader before route changing and hiding them after completing route change

Comment: This is a good example too, wish help you : https://dev.to/debosthefirst/how-to-show-a-loading-bar-when-changing-routes-in-nextjs-304e

Comment: Well. Thanks for your response but I got a better one. That is https://github.com/TheSGJ/nextjs-toploader

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**